# Переход на другую активность

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Есть код, который передает отмеченные позиции в listView в другую активность:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] names = { "voron", "milk", "food", "shit", "gg"};
    TextView selection;
    ListView textList;
    Button btn;
    String[] arr;
    String test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // получаем элемент TextView
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        // получаем элемент ListView
        textList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Получаем эелемент Button
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // создаем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, names);
        // устанавливаем для списка адаптер
        textList.setAdapter(adapter);
        // добвляем для списка слушатель
        textList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                selection.setText("");
                SparseBooleanArray sp=textList.getCheckedItemPositions();

                String selectedItems="";
                for(int i=0;i < names.length;i++)
                {
                    if(sp.get(i))
                        selectedItems+=names[i]+",";
                }
                // установка текста элемента TextView
                selection.setText("Выбрано: " + selectedItems);
                // выбранные позиции будут заноситься в checked:
//                int cntChoice = textList.getCount();
//                String checked = "";
                  String delt= ",";
    //                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = textList.getCheckedItemPositions();
    //                for(int i = 0;i< cntChoice;i++){
    //                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)==true){
    //                        checked+= textList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()+" ";
    //                   }
    //  

              }
                // Получение массива для поиска
                arr = selectedItems.split(delt);
                test = selectedItems;
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                Search search = new Search(arr);
                String start = search.print();
                i.putExtra("start",test.toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

При передаче `test = "milk, food"` (Или др. отмеченные позиции) в интенте, 
приложение вылетает. Почему при переходе на др активность приложение вылетает?

**UPD**

Я немного изменил передачу интента: `i.putExtra("start",arr.toString());` - почему массив приобретает такое значение: `String[2]@4598`

p.s. Я понимаю, что код очень сильно захламлен ненужными переменными и закомментированным кодом, я понимаю, что это снижает его читабельность, извините.

Comment: Можешь предоставить, что пишется в Log'ах?

Comment: Я думаю вы не объявили активити в манифесте.Либо приводите логи

Comment: @Михаил я могу официально назвать себя идиотом. Вся проблема крылась в принятии интента второй активностью. Можешь ответить на новый мой вопрос? Я немного изменил передачу интента: 'i.putExtra("start",arr.toString());'  - почему массив приобретает такое значение: 'String[2]@4598' ?

Comment: Если вы хотите строку передать, то пишите Arrays.toString(arr)

Comment: А вообще интент вроде умеет прямо массивы передавать. На выходе просто дергайте getStringArrayExtra

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати еще кое-что теперь мне нужно вывести содержимого файла. В целом все хорошо, но так как еще плохо знаком с java  и android studio не знаю куда поместить его и как указать к нему путь, что бы на выходе не получить java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Answer (score 1):

У массива метод `toString` возвращает его "дамп", тоесть тип, размер и хешкод. Чтобы передать коллекцию строк используйте `putStringArrayExtra`.